# Is it possible to upgrade my project from spark to blaze using firebase or gcp CLI?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cli

How can I upgrade my project from the spark plan to the blaze plan using the firebase CLI? If it's possible.

Or maybe I can use the GCP CLI to enable billing on my project?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any relevant APIs in either the [REST API for managing projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest) or the [Admin SDK for managing projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.projectManagement.ProjectManagement-1), so I think this isn't possible today. It's a valid [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) though, so I recommend filing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gcloud CLI to link a billing account to your firebase project.

1. Get the `ACCOUNT_ID` of the billing account you want to be billed.

   ```bash
   gcloud beta billing accounts list

   ACCOUNT_ID            NAME                        OPEN  MASTER_ACCOUNT_ID
   0X0X0X-0X0X0X-0X0X0X  Example Account             True
   ```

   https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/billing/accounts/list
2. Link your `PROJECT_ID` with that `ACCOUNT_ID`

   ```bash
   gcloud beta billing projects link PROJECT_ID --billing-account 0X0X0X- 0X0X0X-0X0X0X
   ```

   https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/billing/projects/link

##### Note

It will not show up in the UI as **Blaze Plan**. *(This seems to be a bug)*

If you deploy for example functions to that account it will work without problems. And after that if will show up as **Blaze Plan**