# Is there a way to create a Firebase project using the Firebase CLI?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-tools

I want to ask if it's possible to create a Firebase project from the command line and automatically upgrade it to the Blaze plan? The official docs only refer to creating a Firebase project using the online console, however, it does not provide guidance on how to create / initialize the project using the CLI.

Is there a way to do that using the CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it this way: `firebase init hosting`

Select `Create a new project` and then follow the instructions

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there also a way to do it with one command? Or in other words, it would be done inside of a github workflow to initialize a development pipeline. Any solution for that? And if it possible to do so, would there be to automatically upgrade the new project to the Blaze plan?

Comment: @ethadvocate123 You might want to add more information in your question that describes what you're trying to do - specifically - that you want to create the project automatically without typing anything at the console. Otherwise, this answer is techincally answering your question just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The [CLI reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#management-commands) says there is a command `projects:create` that:

> Creates a new Google Cloud project, then adds Firebase resources to the new project.

Running the command with help:

```
$ firebase projects:create --help
Usage: firebase projects:create [options] [projectId]

creates a new Google Cloud Platform project, then adds Firebase resources to the project

Options:
  -n, --display-name <displayName>     (optional) display name for the project
  -o, --organization <organizationId>  (optional) ID of the parent Google Cloud Platform organization under
                                       which to create this project
  -f, --folder <folderId>              (optional) ID of the parent Google Cloud Platform folder in which to
                                       create this project
  -h, --help                           output usage information
```

You should arrange for the CLI to have an auth token available for the account that should own the project, as suggested by the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#cli-ci-systems).

There are no documented billing operations provided by the Firebase CLI. You will likely need to manually associate your credit card with the project after you create it.

Also see: [Is it possible to upgrade my project from spark to blaze using firebase or gcp CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66120493/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-my-project-from-spark-to-blaze-using-firebase-or-gcp-c)